Unable to connect to internet after upgrading to ubuntu 24.04
I upgraded my laptop to ubuntu 24.04 from 23.10 yesterday. Laptop is Dell Latitude 3420.  While the upgrade was in progress, I realised that my laptop was not able to connect to wifi. Post the upgrade I tried connecting to wifi but couldn't. So I tried wired connection which also did not work. Then in my wifi profile I added dns 8.8.8.8 and it started to work. However, when I started my laptop today morning - the Network manager is not showing the wired connection as well as my wifi connection.

When I am trying to add new connection from Advanced Network Configuration - I am getting the following error message: Connection add failed. Message recipient disconnected from message bus without replying.
The output of systemctl list-unit-files | grep -i network is attached as screenshot.
The error in journalctl -b 0 -u NetworkManager says Error in network definition: invalid prefix length in address '192.168.2.100/0'


"192.168.2.100/0"
^
 [1716457277.7691] BUG: the profile cannot be stored in keyfile format without becoming unusable: cannot access file: No such file or directory
**
nm:ERROR: src/core/settings/plugins/keyfile/nms-keyfile-writer.c: 551: : assertion failed: ()
I am not able to connect my laptop to internet as of now, hence typing all these outputs.
systemctl output


The problem has been fixed. There was a bad yaml file that had been created. Got the clue for this from the error file that was generated using the journalctl command. Deleted this file after taking a back up and then the network has started working.

Can you maybe share which file exactly you're talking about?

This information doesn't help at all unless you tell us which file it is.

It also doesn't seem to be solved. I just upgraded to 24.04 and now I'm having this problem.
